# Running Intern functional tests using AndroidDriver

Tags: javascript, functional-testing, intern

I've tried to run some Intern functional tests on Android using AndroidDriver (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver), but I was unable to (the test runner hang and never returns, apparently because of an error "socket hang up" occuring when Intern wd.js wrapper issues a command execute('return typeof _*internCoverage !== "undefined" && JSON.stringify(*_internCoverage)') before issuing a get command.

Does anybody tried to run tests on Android, and if yes what did you use ?

Thanks for your help,

Sebastien

Comment: I don’t know what you are asking. “Does Intern work with AndroidDriver?” The answer to that is: Yes, it does.

Comment: My question is "did anyone succeeded in running functional tests with AndroidDriver, and if yes can somebody post an example ?"

Answer (score 0):

“Socket hang up” indicates that the remote Selenium server forcibly terminated the WebDriver connection. It would not indicate an issue with Intern.

Comment: Thanks for your help C Snover. I've posted a comprehensive way to reproduce the issue I observe with android driver as a comment of the following issue ticket on the intern github: https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/44#issuecomment-19201752